# Why the difference in type-inference over the as-pattern in two similar function definitions?

Tags: haskell, type-signature

I have the following two similar function definitions:

```
left f (Left x) = Left (f x)
left _ (Right x) = Right x

left' f (Left x) = Left (f x)
left' _ r@(Right _) = r
```

When I check the type signatures of the two functions, I am confused by the following types:

```
ghci> :t left
left :: (t -> a) -> Either t b -> Either a b
ghci> :t left'
left' :: (a -> a) -> Either a b -> Either a b
```

I suppose `left` and `left'` should be of the same type signature, but the haskell's type inference gives me a suprise.

I can't figure out why the type signatures of `left` and `left'` are different. Can anybody give me some information? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the first one might be a bit more flexible since `t` could conceivably equal `a`.

Comment: @ChaosPandion yes it is, but that's the mystery (to me as well when I've looked at it!) - it's saying the function input `f` must have the same input and output type, but there is nothing obvious in the function definition which would so constrain `f`. In fact the only line which differs in the two definitions doesn't reference `f` at all!

Comment: same thing happens with [the definition of `fmap` for `Const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Functor.Const.html#line-82) btw. the value is repackaged in a *different* `Right`/`Const` constructor (which is polymorphic in the other type).

Comment: What is this "as-pattern" that you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen An "as-pattern" is a pattern that uses the `@` symbol to assign a value to an identifier while also pattern matching on that value. Here that's `r@(Right _)`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the second line of `left'`:

```
left' _ r@(Right _) = r
--      ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^
```

Since you use an as-pattern, you require the input type to be equal to the return type, since clearly they're the exact same value. `left'`'s type is then restricted to something of the form `a -> b -> b`.

This restriction then propogates backwards to in turn restrict the function's type – hopefully you can see how; it's not too difficult.

However, in the second line of `left`, you construct a new value

```
left _ (Right x) = Right x
--                 ^^^^^^^
```

The type of this new value has not been restricted, and thus the same problem doesn't occur; it can be something of the form `a -> b -> c`, which is what you want.

For this reason, the type of `left'` is more restricted than the type of `left`, which is what causes their types to be unequal.

---

*To illustrate this concept more concretely, I will describe to you more precisely how this restriction propogates backwards.*

*We know that `left'`'s signature is of the form `(a -> b) -> Either a q -> Either b q`. However, line 2 dictates that `Either a q = Either b q`, which means that `a = b`, so the type now becomes `(a -> a) -> Either a q -> Either a q`.*

Comment: Related question, borne of the same quirk of types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859917/how-do-i-avoid-writing-this-type-of-haskell-boilerplate-code/

Answer (score 19):

The issue here is that there are some "hidden" types which make the difference. The type inference engine can infer those in the first case, but can't in the second case.

When we use

```
Right :: forall a b. b -> Either a b
```

we actually need to choose what types `a` and `b` are. Fortunately, type inference makes this choice for us in most cases.
Type `b` is easy to choose: it is the type of the value inside the argument of `Right`. Type `a` instead can be anything -- the inference engine has to rely on the context to "force" some choice for `a`. For instance, note that all of these type check:

```
test0 :: Either Int Bool
test0 = Right True

test1 :: Either String Bool
test1 = Right True

test2 :: Either [(Char, Int)] Bool
test2 = Right True
```

Now, in your first function

```
left :: (t -> a) -> Either t b -> Either a b
left f (Left x) = Left (f x)
left _ (Right x) = Right x
```

The first matched `Right x` is actually `Right x :: Either t b`, where the implicit type arguments are chosen to be `t` and `b`. This makes `x` to have type `b`.
With this information, the type inference tries to determine the type for the second `Right x`. There, it can see that it should be of the form `Either ?? b` since `x :: b`, but, as it happened for our `test` examples above, we could use anything for `??`. So the type inference engine chooses another type variable `a` (a type which might be `t`, but could also be something else).

Instead, in the second function

```
left' :: (t -> t) -> Either t b -> Either t b
left' f (Left x) = Left (f x)
left' _ r@(Right _) = r
```

we give a name (`r`) to the `Right _` pattern. As above, that is inferred to have type `Either t b`. However, now we use the name `r` on the right of the `=`, so type inference does not have to infer anything there, and can (in fact, *must*) simply reuse the type it has already inferred for `r`. This makes the output type to be the same `Either t b` as the one for the input, and in turn this forces `f` to be of type `t -> t`.

If this is confusing, you could try to completely avoid type inference and provide an explicit choice for the types using the syntax `Right @T @U` to choose the function `U -> Either T U`. (You'll need to turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables`, `TypeApplications` extensions for this, though.)
Then we can write:

```
left :: forall t a b. (t -> a) -> Either t b -> Either a b
left f (Left x) = Left @a @b (f x)
left _ (Right x) = Right @a @b x
                      -- ^^ -- we don't have to pick @t here!
```

We can also have

```
left :: forall t b. (t -> t) -> Either t b -> Either t b
left f (Left x) = Left @t @b (f x)
left _ (Right x) = Right @t @b x
```

and it would work just fine. GHC prefers the first type since it is more general, allowing `a` to be anything (including `t`, but also including other types).

There's no type application to specify in the second definition, since it reuses the same value `r` on the right hand side as on the left:

```
left' :: forall t b. (t -> t) -> Either t b -> Either t b
left' f (Left x) = Left @t @b (f x)
left' _ r@(Right x) = r
                   -- ^^ -- can't pick @a here! it's the same as on the LHS
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanations!